# How do I add the PHP MongoDB driver to Amazon AMI?

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2, pecl

Typically, one would `sudo pecl install mongodb`, however, I need php-devel to do this. And I can't install php-devel because it conflicts with Amazon's pre-installed PHP.

**How can I install the PHP driver for MongoDB on my Amazon AMI EC2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on AWS using Amazon Linux and Mongodb PHP driver.
My problem was that i was using php 5.6 and when i tryed to install php-devel it returned me the error that this was already pre-installed on my system. To solve the problem i installed the `php56-devel` and then `sudo pecl install mongodb`

Hope it help.